# Build tree from flat QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, recursion

i have problem with `QStandardItemModel`. I want to get values from one model (id, name, parent) and build tree in another model.

First i'm getting all childrens of any parent to `QMultiMap<int,QStandardItem*> childrenIndexes`:

```
getChildrens()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < tableModel->rowCount() ; i++ )
    {

        QStandardItem* item_ptr = tableModel->item(i,1);
        int parent;
        if(tableModel->item(i,2)->text() == "null")
        {
            parent = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            parent = tableModel->item(i,2)->text().toInt();
        }

        childrenIndexes.insert(parent, item_ptr);
    }
}
```

Multimap builds fine, in next step i recursively call building function. Starting from root (Item 1):

```
void addChildrens(QStandardItem* item)
{
    int id = tableModel->item(tableModel->indexFromItem(item).row(),0)->text().toInt();
QString name = tableModel->item(tableModel->indexFromItem(item).row(),1)->text();
qDebug() << "Parsing item: " << name;
int parent;

if(tableModel->item(tableModel->indexFromItem(item).row(),2)->text() == "null")
{
    qDebug() << "Got root!";
    item = new QStandardItem(name);
    treeModel->appendRow(item);
    parent = -1;
}
else
{
    parent = tableModel->item(tableModel->indexFromItem(item).row(),2)->text().toInt();
}
qDebug("Got %d childrens!",childrenIndexes.values(id).count());
for(int i = 0 ; i < childrenIndexes.values(id).count() ; i++)
{
    QStandardItem* newItem = childrenIndexes.values(id).at(i);
    qDebug() << newItem->text();
    item->appendRow(newItem->clone());
    addChildrens(newItem);
}
}
```

Unfortunately my tree got only childrens of root. Where is problem?

[image]